# I have question regarding sql database and its view logic?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api

[Database for gold casting application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvpWV.png)

I am writing a VS 2015 Angular & C# ASP.NET Web API project for gold casters. So far I have created this database. I need help in verifying whether this is valid or not.

The system operations as follow:

1. User can add new accounts.
2. User can then go to weight in view where user can add the weight in for an account and rati(gold unit) field as you can see in database transaction table.
3. User will then add weight out for account in separate view designed for weight out and if rati is not set in previous step user will do it here and some calculations will perform and step 1 and other field of transaction table will be filled with values.

**NOTE** user can do step 3 with performing step 2 and later add weight in for account.

I am confused with the logic of step 3 that how I will implement it and how can save and update in the table transaction? Please help me in this regard!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to help as much as I can here, not really understanding the problem in depth and go from there.

### Solution 1

This solution will work even with page refresh

1. User account addition. This should be pretty straghtforward. Create the `user-add.component`, create the api call `POST http://api-url/user` and call it when you have the data. A simple row will be inserted in your Account table.
   **(question for you)** -> Why isn't the user table connected to the Account, since it's the user that creates the accounts?
2. Second view or third view. User navigates to each of the two steps with whatever order they like to. So what can you do.

   - In your database access layer you need to somehow generate a `CreateOrUpdate` function for your transaction. This will check if the transaction exists and then add it. This check could be as simple as checking that a TransactionID was sent from the UI and verifying it's existence
   - In your database table, you need to have the `weight in` and `weight out` and maybe even the Rati as nullable values. What you can and probably should do though, is that you check that at least one of the values are inserted. (check [mysql check constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html)
   - This way, whatever your user does first you create the **Transaction** row with at least one value, get the TransactionID back to update your local data, and then send a new **Transaction** to your api with the full data and update the row accordingly. The **nullable** checks, will help you with that.

### Solution 2

This solution will not work with page refresh.

You can maintain the same **Transaction** object in your angular application. Just create an angular service, and store the **Transaction** object in there. Pass the transaction id (create a unique number in your frontend) around and get it whenever you want.

When the Transaction is ready,`POST` it to your backend.